# how to format date with Two Digit for all properties in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *sss = [dateFormat dateFromString:cDate];
NSString *ok=[dateFormat stringFromDate:sss];
NSLog(@"s is :%@",ok);

NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc]
            initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar
            components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:sss];
NSString *MDY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i/%i",
            [components month],[components day],[components year]];
NSString *HM=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i",
            [components hour],[components second]];
cDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expires on %@ at %@",MDY,HM];
```

i got result: `2012-1-1 19:1:0`
but i want two digit in all format
like this `2012-01-01 19:01:00`

any genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing to use NSDateFormatter will lead to simpler code -- you can include [string literals](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW5) in date format strings. ( Just make sure you release your `NSDateFormatter` when you are done with it )

You can however use `%04i/%02i/%02i` and `%02i:%02i:%02i` if you want to continue to use stringWithFormat )

Comment: both of u right but for the first response i need to vote for him any way u also genius.Thank u so much.

Answer (score 1):

use `@"%02i:%02i"` instead of `@"%i:%i"`

But why can't you just use the NSDateFormatter?